# How to fade images using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

Need a webpage which displays an image for x number of seconds and then fades into another image which also contains a clickable link.

How do I achieve this with javascript? I know this can be done in Flash but it needs to be iPhone compatible.

Comment: Like this? http://www.gruppo4.com/~tobia/cross-slide.shtml#test2

Comment: Something to note Jon, is that iPhone doesn't do amazingly well with lots of javascript effects (for instance have a look at www.bidrivals.com) and can lag which will ruin your effects. Make sure you test thoroughly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) for a Master's Class on manipulating images with JS for galleries and such. Well written, well documented.

Many other good ones out there. Luke, Use the Source! and learn.

Comment: I think your link killed itself :) Another way of doing this manually would be to use jQuery's fadeIn/Out effect, using the callback to initiate a timer, pretty straight forward to do by hand.

Comment: @Jay: Remember links don't kill links, people do! Thanks for the heads up. I agree the fadeIn/fadeOut is good, I was just trying to point him at the All Singing, All Dancing version. I find I always learn more from seeing how a real Pro does it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm gonna give these things a go.

Comment: @Peter Rowell Yeah I agree with you on the "All Singing, All Dancing" version, no point re-inventing the wheel as it'll take you twice as long and will only end up being an arc. +1 for the quotage in all your posts :P

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to use a library like jQuery.  From what I understand iPhone supports jQuery.

Comment: iPhone does indeed support jQuery

Comment: Could be worth mentioning which methods you could use in jQuery and the general concept behind it :) jQuery is supported on iPhone definitely.